# Data migration from PostgreSQL 9.2 to PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-10

I want to migrate data from PostgreSQL 9.2 to PostgreSQL 10. Please, suggest the best way to data migration from old to new versions of PostgreSQL.

Comment: [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) or  [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-server.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use pgdump and restore for this task.

e.g
suppose you have database dbname_pg92 in postgres92
and dbname_pg10 in postgres10
then you can use the below commands for dump and restore

```
./pg_dump -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -Ft dbname_pg92 > dump92.sql.tar
./pg_restore -U postgres -h 172.16.208.155 -p 5432 -d dbname_pg10 dump92.sql.tar
```